# Mouseenter event handler is not working with li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I am trying to add mouseenter event handler to li tag it is showing me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: list.mouseenter is not a function

```js
var list = $('.side_bar_pages ul li')[1];

list.mouseenter(() => {
  console.log('hello world')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="side_bar_pages">
  <ul>
    <li id="clicked_secton">
      <span><img src="/icons/home.svg"></span>
      <a href="/">home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span><img src="/icons/videocamera.svg"></span>
      <a href="/footages">stock footage</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span><img src="/icons/photocamera.svg"></span>
      <a href="/images">stock photos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span><img src="/icons/hot.svg"></span>
      <a href="/new">hot stock</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're accessing a jQuery object by index which returns an Element object. This does not have a `mouseenter` function - hence the error.

If you want to access the second `li` in the collection and return a jQuery object, use `eq()` or `:eq()` instead:

```js
var list = $('.side_bar_pages ul li').eq(1);
// var list = $('.side_bar_pages ul li:eq(1)'); // alternate logic, same result

list.mouseenter(() => {
  console.log('hello world')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="side_bar_pages">
  <ul>
    <li id="clicked_secton">
      <span><img src="/icons/home.svg"></span>
      <a href="/">home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span><img src="/icons/videocamera.svg"></span>
      <a href="/footages">stock footage</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span><img src="/icons/photocamera.svg"></span>
      <a href="/images">stock photos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span><img src="/icons/hot.svg"></span>
      <a href="/new">hot stock</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that `[1]` when you are selecting the `<li>` elements. Remove that and your code works

```js
var list = $('.side_bar_pages ul li')

list.mouseenter(() => {
  console.log('hello world')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="side_bar_pages">
  <ul>
    <li id="clicked_secton">
      <span><img src="/icons/home.svg"></span>
      <a href="/">home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span><img src="/icons/videocamera.svg"></span>
      <a href="/footages">stock footage</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span><img src="/icons/photocamera.svg"></span>
      <a href="/images">stock photos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span><img src="/icons/hot.svg"></span>
      <a href="/new">hot stock</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use the nth-child just like css

```
var li = $('.side_bar_pages ul li:nth-child(1)');

li.on("mouseover", function(){
    console.log("entered");
})
```

;